# how to convert 30 SP to floating points for animation - android

Tags: android

I'm animating a TextView I want the distance to be equal to 30 SP

This is my code

```
mTextView.animate()
    .yBy(50f)                  //I want 30 SP instead of 50f
    .setDuration(800)
    .setStartDelay(300);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conversion factor is the [`scaledDensity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#scaledDensity).

```
int pxValue = spValue * metrics.scaledDensity;
```

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html):

> To access the `DisplayMetrics` members, initialize an object like
>   this:
>
> ```
> DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
> getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
> ```